# How to prepend env var "PATH" in Rust cargo config.toml

Tags: virtualenv, rust-cargo

I am using compile time inline-python and would like to use python v-env for building and testing.

Referring that a python v-env is activated by the following shell script, I believe it should be done by prepending the location of `v-env/bin` to the existing `PATH` for compile time and reverting on the competition.

```bash
...
VIRTUAL_ENV="/Users/<some-path>/<cargo-project>/venv"
export VIRTUAL_ENV

_OLD_VIRTUAL_PATH="$PATH"
PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
export PATH
...
```

Would it be a good way to go for the purpose? If so, how am I supposed to do this?

This is necessary because when I print out the path and import the path like below with a test, they direct system root python.

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {

    use std::env;

    use ct_python::ct_python;

    static python_bin: &'static str = ct_python! {
    import sys
    print('"' + "{}".format(sys.executable) + '"')
    };

    static python_path: &'static str = ct_python! {
    import sys
    print('"' + "{}".format(sys.path) + '"')
    };

    #[test]
    fn venv_test() {
        match env::var("VIRTUAL_ENV") {
            Ok(v) => println!("{}", v),
            Err(e) => println!("{}", e)
            
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn path_print_test() {        
        println!("bin: {}", python_bin);
        println!("path: {}", python_path);
    }
}
```

output:

```bash
running 1 test
bin: /Users/<username>/.rustup/toolchains/nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin/bin/rustc
path: ['/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.10/3.10.9/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages', '/opt/homebrew/opt/python-tk@3.10/libexec']
test signal_proc::tests::path_print_test ... ok
```

I believe the output of the `sys.path` should be `./venv/bin` in order to use arbitrary python libraries and it has to be "prepending" of PATH only for the cargo.

Comment: How does this relate to Rust and Cargo.toml? Please elaborate on what you are doing.

Comment: @Simson Sorry for the vague question. I have added some more detail. Please check :)